# Filling in Missing Values from One Dataset Using Group Means From A Different Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to impute missing values on my test set, and would like to use the same imputations from group means derived from my training set using a pandas `groupby` statement.

I'm familiar with the `transform` method, but am not aware of how to use its output on a *different* dataset.

Right now, here's what I have on my training set:

```
transformer = train.groupby('BldgType')['LotFrontage'].transform('mean')
train['LotFrontage'] = train['LotFrontage'].fillna(transformer)
```

The result of the `groupby statement` looks like this:

[image]

Those are the results I want to use to impute the missing values on my test set.

The following doesn't work, because it uses the index from the training set to infer what the value should be, not the test set:

```
test['LotFrontage'] = test['LotFrontage'].fillna(transformer)
```

Comment: Can you come up with a [MCVE] ?

Comment: Just did.  Accidentally hit the submit button before I had a chance to finish the question.

Comment: are you editing?

Answer (score 2):

One trick is to turned the grouped object into a dataframe and merge it into the test dataframe:

Set up the data:

```
train_data = [     
['A', 1],          
['A', 2],        
['A',2],        
['B',3],       
['B', 4],
['B', 4]
]
train_df = pd.DataFrame(train_data, columns=['group', 'value'])

test_data = [     
['A', 1],          
['A', np.nan],        
['A',np.nan],        
['B',3],       
['B', np.nan],
['B', np.nan]
]
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_data, columns=['group', 'value'])
```

Do the groupby on the training data:

```
group_mean_df = pd.DataFrame(train_df.groupby('group').value.mean()).rename(columns={'value':'group_mean'})
```

Now merge the test data and the group mean data and do the fill na:

```
test_merged = test_df.merge(group_mean_df, left_on='group', right_on='group')
test_merged['value'] = test_merged['value'].fillna(test_merged['group_mean'])
```

You can then drop the 'group_mean' column if you want.